# Define kernel in scikit GaussianProcessRegressor using BayesSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian-process, skopt

**Question: How do I define the kernel of a Gaussian Process Regressor using BayesSearchCV?**

I'm trying to optimize hyperparameters in a gaussian process model using `BayesSearchCV` from `skopt`. It seems that I'm defining the kernel wrong and get a 'TypeError':

```
TypeError: Cannot clone object ''rbf'' (type <class 'str'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' method.
```

**Dummy-Code:**

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from skopt import BayesSearchCV
from skopt.space import Real, Categorical, Integer
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, DotProduct, Matern

X,y = make_regression(100,10)

estimator = GaussianProcessRegressor()

param = {
    'kernel': ['rbf','matern'],
    'n_restarts_optimizer': (5,10),
    'alpha': (1e-5, 1e-2,'log-uniform')
}

opt = BayesSearchCV(
    estimator=estimator,
    search_spaces=param,
    cv=3,
    scoring="r2",
    random_state=42,
    n_iter=3,
    verbose=1,
)   

opt.fit(X, y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, GPR does not seem to support string aliased kernels, at least that holds for the current release.
That raises another issue however, if you supply the `kernel` parameter with a constructor list, skopt is unable to process it (unhashable type). This is still a standing issue as far as I'm aware, though there's a proposed workaround at the bottom of the [issue page](https://github.com/scikit-optimize/scikit-optimize/issues/681).

Another possible workaround is constructing different base estimators with a specific kernel:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from skopt import BayesSearchCV
from skopt.space import Real, Categorical, Integer
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, DotProduct, Matern
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

X,y = make_regression(100,10)

estimator_list = [GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=RBF()),
                  GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=Matern())]

pipe=Pipeline([('estimator',GaussianProcessRegressor())])

param = {
    'estimator': Categorical(estimator_list),
    'estimator__n_restarts_optimizer': (5,10),
    'estimator__alpha': (1e-5, 1e-2,'log-uniform')
}

opt = BayesSearchCV(
    estimator=pipe,
    search_spaces=param,
    cv=3,
    scoring="r2",
    random_state=42,
    n_iter=3,
    verbose=1,
)   

opt.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to use this setup to tune the kernel's hyperparameters? `estimator__kernel_length_scale` is not working. It just draws the length scale once for each kernel and doesn't change anymore in further iterations.

Comment: `estimator__kernel__length_scale` does seem to draw different samples for me. To make sure, you may try to split the grid into a list of two dicts (`param = [{'estimator':[GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=RBF())], 'estimator__kernel__length_scale':Real(1,100), etc},{'estimator': [GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=Matern())], and so on}]` )

Comment: There are different values drawn for `length_scale`, but when I check with `opt.cv_results_['param'][0]` it gives: `OrderedDict([('estimator',
              GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=RBF(length_scale=1))),
             ('estimator__alpha', 0.004466278825224283),
             ('estimator__kernel__length_scale', 0.524774153837845),
             ('estimator__n_restarts_optimizer', 10)])` 
there are different values in the call of the kernel and in `estimator__kernel__length_scale`.